# Reset motherboard after sleep

Tags: virtual-machine, motherboard, sleep, wake-up

I have a problem with my computer.

I put my computer in sleep mode. When I want woke up my computer, the screen turn on and stay black. After that I need to power off the computer with shutting the electricity. The screen stay black, when I restart.

So I need to remove all cable of the motherboard and remove the little battery and wait 5 minutes. After that, a menu display which ask if we want use the last known good CMOS. I press ok and my computer restart. After Windows ask if we want "use the restoration" and "continue with the menu and ignore the restoration". I choice the second. Finally my computer start correctly.

I did not change any hardware in my computer but I bought a UPS and connect my computer to it.

I didn't understand why my computer do that and I can't believe that the UPS is the problem. May be that the old age of my hardware ?

I use this computer to hosting some virtual server with VirtualBox and use WakeOnLan to turn on the computer.

Sorry for my English. I am learning it.

Config :

- GigaByte GA-P55A-UD4
- Intel core I7 860S
- 4 x 4Go Kingston 1600 CL9
- Asus GeForce GTX 660 TI
- Windows 7 Pro 64bit

Answer (score 0):

If pulling your CMOS battery and reinserting it allows it to boot, then step 1 in troubleshooting would be to try a replacement CMOS battery.

Comment: I have change the battery and checked both (new and old) with multi-meter and the problem is not resolve.